# Warning: mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

Запрос в базу:

```
$result = database_select("SELECT p.type_condition AS pay, o.type_condition AS orders, 
          n.type_condition AS news, a.type_condition AS other, s.index AS index, 
          s.login AS login, s.telephone AS telephone
  FROM
    `vixen_erps_services_sms` s
  LEFT JOIN
    `vixen_erps_services_type` p
  ON
    p.type_id = s.pay
  LEFT JOIN
    `vixen_erps_services_type` o
  ON
    o.type_id = s.orders
  LEFT JOIN
    `vixen_erps_services_type` n
  ON
    n.type_id = s.news
  LEFT JOIN
    `vixen_erps_services_type` a
  ON
    a.type_id = s.other"); 

$col = database_numrows($result);
```

Функции:

```
function database_select($select_text){ 
    $query = "$select_text"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    return $result; 
}

function database_numrows($result){ 
    $numrows = mysql_numrows($result); 
    return $numrows; 
}
```

Выкидывает **Warning: mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource**.

Если убираю из выборки поле `index`, то все работает нормально. Но `index` мне нужно выбирать тоже. Не понимаю в чем проблема. Все поля в таблицах БД существуют.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, а в чем смысл функции database_select()?

Comment: Чтобы писать одно слово database_select вместо двух строк кода. Если использовать не функцию - проблема не исчезает.

Comment: A зачем здесь писать двух строк кода? Почему нельзя написать одну - `$result = mysql_query("SELECT p.type_condition...`?

Comment: Суть в том, что не работает независимо от способа обработки запроса.

Comment: То что не работает - это понятно. Я про смысл функции database_select() интересуюсь. "Слово" mysql_query даже короче получается. Откуда две строчки-то берутся?

Comment: Да что вы прицепились ко мне. Какая вам разница каким образом я это делаю?

Comment: Мне интересно. Если не хотите отвечать - не надо. Я не настаиваю. Только не надо нервничать. Мне просто любопытно.

Comment: Просто мне так показалось удобнее, все функции лежат в отдельном файле и я нехитрым способом, когда мне нужно, их вызываю. И читать написанное проще. Может это и быдло-код, но и я не гуру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. поменяй функцию database_select() на такую

   ```
   function database_select($query){ 
       return mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
   }
   ```
2. Возьми index в обратные кавычки, вот так:

   ```
   `index`
   ```

Comment: Query was empty

Comment: Почему запрос может быть пустым? Не понимаю. Все поля в таблице есть, данные в них тоже. Запрос написан верно.

Comment: Потому что я не дописал сначала переменную в функции, но потом исправил. Надо взять новый вариант,

Comment: Так дело то не в переменной, я сейчас вообще функцию не использую. Результат тот же. query пустой. При чем уже даже независимо от того, выбираю я поле `index` или нет.

Comment: Дело именно в переменной. Пустой запрос означает что запрос был пустым. То есть никакого запроса в функцию не передали.

Comment: Не изменилось ничего, хоть с функцией, хоть без функции.

Comment: С вашей функцией почему-то не работает, с моей заработало, после занесения названий всех полей в обратные кавычки.